# What is this AC power connector for a Hughes TWTA?

Tags: connector, microwave, test-equipment

I've been picking up some microwave power equipment off of eBay recently and ended up with a Hughes TWTA (1277H04, 20W in the Ku band) on the cheap. Unfortunately it did not come with a power cable and I'm bamboozled about the connector.

[image: The wily connector in question]

I have an 1177 (pretty much the same model with a lower power tube) that has an IEC 320 C14. It doesn't look like that connector is meant to fit over this one. It looks a little bit like a Brazilian IEC N connector but the center pin here is 1/8th of an inch in diameter. The power input instructions say 117 volts @ 3 amps.

Might just be an unfinished amp, who knows. I could probably unsolder this and replace it with a standard connector but I'd rather not fiddle with it if I don't have to. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: looks like a Hewlett Packard AC power receptacle from the 1970's era. Centre pin is ground.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Glen's hint, I managed to track the cable type down - it is indeed a Hewlett Packard receptacle from the 1970s. It is either known as a 163 or PH163 connector, and was one of the more popular of the predecessors of the IEC C13/C14 - used from 1959 until the late 1970s.

If you need a cable of this kind you can probably find one under the manufacturer name of Belden or Volex (model 17952).

You can find some more info on obsolete connectors from this page (unfortunately only available via Google caching ATM...save it if you need it):

https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:AbLwc6-pTpMJ:https://www.cs.ubc.ca/~hilpert/e/powerConn/index.html+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us